# Photo enlargment with moving feature in original limits

Tags: jquery, photo, zooming

Do you know any jq plugin or jq functions to enable photo enlargment which is used [here](http://shopeu.ecco.com/uk/en/ecco/ecco-touch-15_4666740/8363375?navId=182) while you are hovering the mouse at the main photo of a product? That is photo must be zoomed in and be moveable in its original limits

Comment: Please have a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)! This is no question based on a existing programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I need to use Jquery Zoom - http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/